# Getting 404 for manually configured Spring Cloud route

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I have been learning Spring Cloud Gateway following a course on Udemy.
Accessing the UserApplication directly from its assigned port through gateway.

Gateway- application.properties

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-status-check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath\=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /${segment}
```

UserApplication - application.properties

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=users-ws
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/status/check")
    public String checkStatus() {
        return "Working at port : "+ this.env.getProperty("local.server.port");
    }
    
}
```

[image: Getting same 404 error with or without Bearer Token passed in Header]

Comment: My guess is the 404 is coming from downstream and `RewritePath\=` should remove the slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header: Authorization's value must be startWith Bearer ,
ie. Bearer ABCCCC

Answer (score 0):

1st thing the if you are taking the JWT(Json Web Token) use - Bearer before giving the token.

example - **Bearer ABCCC**

we generally gets **404 not found** error when the server is not able to  locate the URL which is getting hit.

please check your url - http://localhost:8082/users-ws/users/status/check

as per my understanding the url should be - http://localhost:8082/users/status/check

Comment: Path is correct I believe as I have mentioned RewritePath as users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /${segment}